# Error within model_function for XGBoost in R

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to follow the tutorial here for applying XGBoost to a time series:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecastML/vignettes/grouped_forecast.html

Everything is working copying the included code until creating the model_function.

```
# The value of outcome_col can also be set in train_model() with train_model(outcome_col = 1).
model_function <- function(data, outcome_col = 1) {
  
  # xgboost cannot handle missing outcomes data.
  data <- data[!is.na(data[, outcome_col]), ]

  indices <- 1:nrow(data)
  
  set.seed(224)
  train_indices <- sample(1:nrow(data), ceiling(nrow(data) * .8), replace = FALSE)
  test_indices <- indices[!(indices %in% train_indices)]

  data_train <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[train_indices, 
                                                           -(outcome_col), drop = FALSE]),
                                     label = as.matrix(data[train_indices, 
                                                            outcome_col, drop = FALSE]))

  data_test <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[test_indices, 
                                                          -(outcome_col), drop = FALSE]),
                                    label = as.matrix(data[test_indices, 
                                                           outcome_col, drop = FALSE]))

  params <- list("objective" = "reg:linear")
  watchlist <- list(train = data_train, test = data_test)
  
  set.seed(224)
  model <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = data_train, params = params, 
                              max.depth = 8, nthread = 2, nrounds = 30,
                              metrics = "rmse", verbose = 0, 
                              early_stopping_rounds = 5, 
                              watchlist = watchlist)

  return(model)
}
```

I get an error that the data is a character string and not a matrix for the xgb.Matrix portion when I utilize that function in:

```
model_results_cv <- forecastML::train_model(lagged_df = data_train,
                                            windows = windows,
                                            model_name = "xgboost",
                                            model_function = model_function, 
                                            use_future = FALSE)
```

Error in xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[train_indices, -(outcome_col),  :
'data' has class 'character' and length 2099328.
'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.
A model returned class 'try-error' for validation window 1Error in xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[train_indices, -(outcome_col),  :
'data' has class 'character' and length 2078336.

I have tried pulling the calculation out of the function and assigning it to a variable and using that as the data = argument:

```
model_function <- function(data, outcome_col = 1) {
  
  # xgboost cannot handle missing outcomes data.
  data <- data[!is.na(data[, outcome_col]), ]

  indices <- 1:nrow(data)
  
  set.seed(224)
  train_indices <- sample(1:nrow(data), ceiling(nrow(data) * .8), replace = FALSE)
  test_indices <- indices[!(indices %in% train_indices)]
  
  data_matrix_train <- as.matrix(data[train_indices, -outcome_col, drop = FALSE])
  label_matrix_train <- as.matrix(data[train_indices, -outcome_col, drop = FALSE])
  
  data_matrix_test <- as.matrix(data[test_indices, -outcome_col, drop = FALSE])
  label_matrix_test <- as.matrix(data[test_indices, -outcome_col, drop = FALSE])

  print(class(data_matrix_train)

  data_train <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = data_matrix_train,
                                     label = label_matrix_train)

  data_test <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = data_matrix_test,
                                    label = label_matrix_test)

  params <- list("objective" = "reg:linear")
  watchlist <- list(train = data_train, test = data_test)

  set.seed(224)
  model <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = data_train, params = params,
                              max.depth = 8, nthread = 2, nrounds = 30,
                              metrics = "rmse", verbose = 0,
                              early_stopping_rounds = 5,
                              watchlist = watchlist)

  return(model)
}
```

If I do this and ask the function to return the class of data_matrix_test just before the call to xgb.DMatrix using the following code it returns:

```
model_function(data_train$horizon_1)
```

[1] "matrix" "array"

but I still get the same error. I have also tried using do.call() to initiate the xgb.DMatrix function with the same error. I have attempted to investigate passing variables generated within functions without success.

Is there something about how xgb.DMatrix is being called within a function that is affecting the attributes of the as.matrix statement?

Comment: do you have columns in your independent variables that are factors ?

Comment: the bouy_id is character when I run str(data_train). There is a line that is supposed to convert that to a numeric. I have tried to run that part again without it helping. But I will start it over, if that's the problem I likely messed up that step somehow.

Comment: Clearing everything and starting from scratch (again) fixed it. Not sure how I missed that several times. Thank you.